# How I can display custom attribute on product view page under description Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have tried couple of ways that are already mention on Stack, but none worked for me.

What i have done so far is here....

1. First i have created `attribute` in the back-end and assigned it to
   default `attribute set`. attribute code is `youtubevideo`
2. I put following piece of code in `catalog_product_view.xml`

   ```
   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.video" template="product/view/video.phtml" group="detailed_info">
   <arguments>
       <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getYoutubevideo</argument>
       <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">youtubevideo</argument>
       <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">youtubevideo</argument>
       <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
       <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Video</argument>
   </arguments>
   ```

its not working with this way , the `video.phtml` file is copy of `attribute.phtml` file. which is present on the same path.

Its work if i change in xml `video.phtml` to `attribute.phtml` , But it shown on under tab. I don't want to show it in tab.

I'm working on `Magento 2.0.9`

What else way to shown it on product page somewhere else.

Any help would be appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have similar requirement to show some text attribute values on frontend on product view page after the short description.

I have modified `catalog_product_view.xml` and added my own template file in my custom theme.

**app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main product-shop col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.measurements" template="product/view/customattribute.phtml" after="product.info.overview">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getMeasurements</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="measurements"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/customattribute.phtml**

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue) { ?>
    <div class="product attibute <?php echo $_className?>">
    <div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I have taken reference from [http://www.mohannatarajan.com/magento/magento2-get-product-attribute-value][1]

Answer (score 0):

When you create the attribute, make sure that under `Storefront Properties` tab, you have `Allow HTML Tags on Storefront` set to Yes

I created a download link and only displaying if text input field is not empty. I also added the `block` in the xml file but I did not add any arguments. Instead I added the code below into my `.phtml` file.

Hopefully this is helpful.

XML, added into `product.info.main` container: (might want to change the block class to see if that is why you can't view it)

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.downloads" template="product/view/downloads.phtml"/>
```

PHTML file:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
?>

<?php if ($_product->getData('download_spec_link')): ?><div class="download-link"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getData('download_spec_link'); ?>"> Download Specification</a></div><?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried this , but unfortunately its not working.

Comment: Did you use exact code above? Removed the arguments in the xml and replaced the attribute code with your attribute code for the.phtml? Also, is the block placed in the reference container named="content"?

Comment: of course i used my attribute code, My block is under the content of product_view xml of theme

Comment: @AdeelIshfaq is there a way you can send me those 2 files (catalag_product_view.xml and the video.phtml)? That way I can add it into my test magento and see if it's working for me and if not, what the reason is? amyl [at] ahernit.com

Comment: @Amy Ling this worked for me! thx