# Magento 2: Custom Attribute into Product Page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, xml

I am trying to add custom attribute into product page, but for some reason its generating error even after running all imp commands.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description"
                   name="product.info.my.info" 
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">GetMyInfo</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">my_info</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="my_info"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
```

Do i have to describe the GetMyInfo method some where ?

Here is error generating on product page

```
 1 exception(s):
 Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor::GetMyInfo

 Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor::GetMyInfo
 <pre>#1 include('/var/www/vhosts/...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
 #2 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description#000000004c1cab8400000000466be1bb#, '/var/www/vhosts/...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
 #3 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/vhosts/...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
 #4 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1099]
 #5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1103]
 #6 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:673]
 #7 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:564]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description"
                   name="product.info.my.info" 
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getMyInfo</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">my_info</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="my_info"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
```

Test first in the developer mode.

Comment: what is difference ?

Comment: issue is even i have now removed the code still the exception error exists even after clear cache everything

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException):

Comment: Difference is getMyInfo I have changed GetMyInfo to getMyInfo.

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/173716/1968

Comment: yes but this error not going now after fixing code

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor::GetMyInfo

I did fixed with small get

Still it showing error, i did runn compiled command too, does it saved GetMyInfo somewhere from where i have to remove it now ?

Comment: clear pub/static/frontend and generated/ and try again.

Comment: Still same error (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor::GetMyInfo